# iPhone 6 support BLE 4.2, but no example

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Found iPhone 6 support BLE 4.2

Compare to BLE 4.0,v4.2 has big improvement on security, like it support ECDH.

I want to do some test base on ECC.  Any example for it? I couldn't find any API change in iOS 9.1 API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly simple, on iOS anyway. All you need is to flag your characteristic and set a permission, as shown below. The rest is taken care of.

```
emailCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc]
    initWithType:emailCharacteristicUUID
    properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
    | CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired
    value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadEncryptionRequired];
```

Actually, it came with iOS 6.0 (just discovered that) ! It may not be built nativelly into the ble 4.0 chips, but it is built on top of basic ble specifications, and iOS takes care of it software-side.

A popup should appear on iOS devices asking you to allow the pairing (trusted channel). Now, I have no idea how that works when you are dealing with a micro-controller and a ble chip directly. My guess: accepting the pairing on the iOS device is all you need.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH5-SW9

CBCharacteristicProperties:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties